# зачем maven surefire плагин копирует классы

Tags: maven

из стандартной папки classes в test-classes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это не Surefire делает - он только выполняет тесты и генерирует отчет.

> The Surefire Plugin is used during the test phase of the build
>   lifecycle to **execute the unit tests** of an application. **It generates**
>   **reports** in two different file formats:

Это делает сам Maven, следуя соглашению каталогов. И из classes ничего не берется, в `target/**` вообще только выхлоп.

В ходе выполнения фазы `compile` исходные файлы берутся из `project.build.sourceDirectory` компилируются и помещаются в `project.build.outputDirectory`. Аналогично, при `test-compile` берутся файлы тестов из `project.build.testSourceDirectory` компилируются и помещаются в `project.build.testOutputDirectory`.

где

```
project.build.sourceDirectory = src/main/java
project.build.testSourceDirectory = src/test/java
project.build.outputDirectory = target/classes
project.build.testOutputDirectory = target/test-classes
```

Переопределить можно так:

```
<build>
    <testSourceDirectory>src/any/test</testSourceDirectory>
    <testOutputDirectory>target/any/test</testOutputDirectory>
</build>
```

И вот именно потому, что исходники и тесты компилируются в разные каталоги, которые определены в [Maven Model](http://maven.apache.org/ref/3.0.3/maven-model/maven.html), плагины вроде Surefire и знают где их брать.